# PHPUnit требует mbstring хотя он есть

Tags: php, laravel, docker, phpunit

Запустил ларавел в докер контейнере. Написал тесты. Запускаю через артизан и получаю `PHPUnit requires the "mbstring" extension.`

Изменил докерфайл для данного контейнера добавив `apt-get install -y libonig-dev && docker-php-ext-install mbstring`. Пересобрал контейнер, но пхпюнит все равно бунтует. Читал что надо где-то как-то включить еще `mbstring`, но не знаю где и надо ли в дебиане это делать.

Сам Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1.16-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      apt-utils \
      libonig-dev \
      libpq-dev \
      libpng-dev \
      libzip-dev \
      zip unzip \
      git && \
      docker-php-ext-install pdo && \
      docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql && \
      docker-php-ext-install pgsql && \
      docker-php-ext-install bcmath && \
      docker-php-ext-install gd && \
      docker-php-ext-install zip && \
      docker-php-ext-install mbstring && \
      apt-get clean && \
      rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install XDebug
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать версию `php8.1-mbstring` без docker-php-ext-install

Comment: Или отдельно для докера ставить расширения, аля `RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions mbstring bcmath zip pgsql pdo pdo_pgsql gd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ларчик очень просто открывался (-_-), как обычно. Видимо косяк с правами, про такое тоже читал, но было лень лезть в тему прав линукс. **Данная проблема решается запуском `php artisan test` непосредственно в докер контейнере, а не из вне**, как это делал я. (Был уже вечер, видимо совсем затроил). Всем большое спасибо за участие, всех обнял, поднял, перевернул, поставил.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать следующим образом:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    php8.1-mbstring \
```

Если будет недостаточно, то можно прописать в php.ini:

```
[mbstring]
mbstring.language = all
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
mbstring.http_input = auto
mbstring.http_output = UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation = On
mbstring.detect_order = UTF-8
mbstring.substitute_character = none;
mbstring.func_overload = 0
mbstring.strict_encoding = Off
```

Comment: Получаю ошибку: `#0 25.81 E: Unable to locate package php8.1-mbstring
#0 25.81 E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-mbstring'
#0 25.81 E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.1-mbstring'`